# RQ Job queued but not run

Tags: python, redis, python-rq

I'm having issues enqueuing jobs with [Python-RQ](https://python-rq.org/), jobs seems well enqueued but they don't run, crash or whatever they have to do.

The process I'm doing is the following:

1. Run redis server on localhost:

```
loren@RONDAN1:/mnt/c/Users/rondan$ sudo service redis-server restart
[sudo] password for loren:
Stopping redis-server: redis-server.
Starting redis-server: redis-server.
loren@RONDAN1:/mnt/c/Users/rondan$ rq info
default      | 0
1 queues, 0 jobs total

72a81f7d4cde4e7c865b178772766aef (RONDAN1 95): idle default
1 workers, 1 queues

Updated: 2021-03-16 19:26:52.459427
```

2. Run the worker on other bash:

```
loren@RONDAN1:/mnt/c/Users/rondan$ rq worker --with-scheduler
19:26:42 Worker rq:worker:72a81f7d4cde4e7c865b178772766aef: started, version 1.7.0
19:26:42 Subscribing to channel rq:pubsub:72a81f7d4cde4e7c865b178772766aef
19:26:42 *** Listening on default...
19:26:42 Trying to acquire locks for default
19:26:42 Scheduler for default started with PID 98
19:26:42 Cleaning registries for queue: default
```

3. Run my python demo code (This code works without redis queues in the async way):

**main.py**

```
import lightquery as lq
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue

queue = Queue(connection=Redis())


def queue_tasks():
    queue.enqueue(lq.print_task, 5)
    queue.enqueue_in(timedelta(seconds=10), lq.print_numbers, 5)


def main():
    queue_tasks()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**lightquery.py**

```
import time

def print_task(seconds):
    print("Starting task")
    for num in range(seconds):
        print(num, ". Hello World!")
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Task completed")


def print_numbers(seconds):
    print("Starting num task")
    for num in range(seconds):
        print(num)
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Task to print_numbers completed")
```

4. After running the code the execution ends properly and the job is enqueued:

```
loren@RONDAN1:/mnt/c/Users/rondan$ rq worker --with-scheduler
19:26:42 Worker rq:worker:72a81f7d4cde4e7c865b178772766aef: started, version 1.7.0
19:26:42 Subscribing to channel rq:pubsub:72a81f7d4cde4e7c865b178772766aef
19:26:42 *** Listening on default...
19:26:42 Trying to acquire locks for default
19:26:42 Scheduler for default started with PID 98
19:26:42 Cleaning registries for queue: default
19:28:43 default: lightquery.print_task(5) (02a07849-64b5-4f44-8e0b-89bb466110ee)
```

I tried to display the jobs queue after adding the job to it and prints an empty array (Maybe that can help you to give me a solution)

**EDITED**

```
loren@RONDAN1:/mnt/c/Users/rondan$ sudo service redis-server restart
Stopping redis-server: redis-server.
Starting redis-server: redis-server.
loren@RONDAN1:/mnt/c/Users/rondan$ rq info
default      | 0
1 queues, 0 jobs total

0 workers, 1 queues

Updated: 2021-03-17 07:59:13.587043
loren@RONDAN1:/mnt/c/Users/rondan$
```

```
loren@RONDAN1:/mnt/c/Users/rondan$ rq worker --with-scheduler
08:00:15 Worker rq:worker:b1fcdaaf1c224e239d28f9fdf8509a1a: started, version 1.7.0
08:00:15 Subscribing to channel rq:pubsub:b1fcdaaf1c224e239d28f9fdf8509a1a
08:00:15 *** Listening on default...
08:00:15 Trying to acquire locks for default
08:00:15 Scheduler for default started with PID 65
08:00:15 Cleaning registries for queue: default
```

```
loren@RONDAN1:/mnt/c/Users/rondan$ rq info
default      | 0
1 queues, 0 jobs total

b1fcdaaf1c224e239d28f9fdf8509a1a (RONDAN1 62): idle default
1 workers, 1 queues

Updated: 2021-03-17 08:02:29.590837
```

Comment: If you really run the commands in the given order, then it seems to me like there is another worker consuming the jobs as in the `rq info` command's output, it says `1 workers`.

Comment: Yeah, It was a error in the code I pasted, just edited, the same happens @OndřejXichtSvětlík

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the problem was the way I import the module...

Use

```
from lightquery import print_task
...
queue.enqueue(print_task, 5)
```

Instead of:

```
import lightquery as lq
...
queue.enqueue(lq.print_task(), 5)
```